# Unity - showing self-written array in the inspector

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I wrote my own object for Unity. It can hold up information about the gameObject to spawn and the count of it. I use it for arrays so the arrays can have 2 values.

```
public class ChestValue // my own object for "Arrays with 2 values"
{
    public ChestValue(GameObject prefab, int count) // fill the data
    {
        ItemToSpawn = prefab;
        SpawnCount = count;
    }

    public GameObject ItemToSpawn { get; private set; }
    public int SpawnCount { get; private set; }
}
```

So writing

```
[SerializeField]
ChestValue[] information;
```

does not work, the object does not show up in the inspector.

I know, ChestValue is an object. But is there a way to archieve it?

Like writing your own Array / Tuple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, simply add the [System.Serializable] decoration to the top of your class: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Serializable.html

You may however need to add a default constructor to your class for this to work and you will need to switch out the properties ItemToSpawn and SpawnCount with plain variables so the inspector can see and serialize them (you can have properites too I think but it requires a lot more fiddling in editor code).

```
[System.Serializable] // tells unity that this class is serializable and therefore it can show up in the inspector
public class ChestValue 
{
     // Pretty sure you need a default constructor as the class is serializable
    public ChestValue(){}
    public ChestValue(GameObject prefab, int count) // fill the data
    {
        ItemToSpawn = prefab;
        SpawnCount = count;
    }

    // switched properties to variables so the editor can 'see' them
    public GameObject ItemToSpawn;
    public int SpawnCount;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to mention another problem which is using properties. Unity cannot serialize properties `"{ get; private set; }`....

Comment: I don't understand you. You should edit that into your answer so that OP wouldn't make that mistake again. You only have `[System.Serializable]` for now.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're seeing but I most certainly removed the properties and switched to public GameObject ItemToSpawn/public int SpawnCount in my edit

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you

Comment: I know that. Your code is **correct**. It's not about correct code. It's about telling OP what is wrong with their code(explaining your answer). You added that OP should add `[System.Serializable]`..Why not also add that Unity also does not serialize `{ get; private set; }`. That's what I am saying.